# Show custom post type taxonomy with URL in WordPress site

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I am working in a WordPress site that has a custom post type of `photos`. I have added a custom taxonomy caller `category`. I want to show the custom `category` name with URL. But for some reason it is showing blank. How can I fix it? 
Here are my codes I am trying

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'photos',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged')
);
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);

?>

<?php
if ($the_query->have_posts()):

    while ($the_query->have_posts()):
        $the_query->the_post();
        ?>

        <div>Meal type: <?php echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'category', '', ', ', ''); ?></div>                     

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else: ?>
    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your question is why the "div" tag in the while loop is appearing blank, that's due to the while loop's conditions not being met. One or more of your arguments are returning false.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'photos',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged')
);
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);

?>

<?php
if ($the_query->have_posts()):

    while ($the_query->have_posts()):
        $the_query->the_post();
        ?>
```

Essentially, WP_Query is calling multiple classes such as WP_Tax_Query and WP_Meta_Query and is doing an SQL request as follows based on the criteria you provided:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  
WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'photos' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))  
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

It's searching to see if there are posts that fit the criteria that you specified, a post type of "photos" and a "published" status. I would assume that it's not finding these criteria and is returning with a value of false.

More information:

[WP_QUERY](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: @AmarB It's good practice to tag people if they're not the author of the post. I didn't actually need to tag you since you're the asker of thie specific question, but wanted to show you how. Also **Very nice job** on your edit to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with your custom taxonomy name `category`, because `category` is already associated with post type `post`. So you are getting a blank output.

**How to fix**:: rename `category` to `photos_cat` *(or with any name of your wish)*.

Hope this helps!